# Using InnerIterator

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

How can I iterate over sparse matrix using Eigen library in C++?
I want to iterate over sparse matrix in order to raise it of power of 2.

I have a sparse matrix

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> L(N, N);
```

I used triplets to fill matrix with values:

```
std::vector< Eigen::Triplet<double> > triplets_L;
```

I fill triplets with matrix values and then setup L matrix

```
L.setFromTriplets(triplets_L.begin(), triplets_L.end());
```

Now I would like to iterate L matrix each column using iterator below:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator;
```

How can I correctly write a loop to iterate over L matrix using InnerIterator, as I do not know how to use InnerIterator?

Comment: Just follow the example [there](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2), but using `it.valueRef() = ...` if you want to modify the elements. Nonetheless, for squaring the coefficients, just do `L = L.cwiseAbs2()`, or `L.coeffs() = L.coeffs().cwiseAbs2()` to work inplace.

Comment: Thank you for the reference it helps. If I have totally **symmetric matrix** how would I do square matrix by itself (L*L) **in a loop** ? Because it iterates trough columns.

Comment: oh, do you want to compute the matrix product or to square the coefficients? In the first case just write `L = L*L`  and Eigen will do the job.

Comment: I would like to do L*L, but the problem is that I would like to do this in a loop because I have to replace 4th row of matrix L squared by [0,0,0,1,0,0], assuming the the matrix L is 6x6.

Comment: Ok it seems that compiler lets me do L = L*L. But how to replace one row of the matrix by [0,0,0,1,0,0], assuming it is symmetric, I do not know, because it iterates columns not rows:  `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(L, i); it; ++it) { } }`

Comment: If your matrix is 6x6, then please don't use a sparse matrix but a plain dense `MatrixXd`. Then do `L.row(i) = ..`.

Comment: My matrix is not 6x6 it was just example I have really large one. When I set the sparse from triplets, do I have to change row before this line or after? `L.setFromTriplets(triplets_L.begin(), triplets_L.end());`

Comment: `L.setFromTriplets(...)` erase the content of `L` and rebuilt it from the triplets. If you need to modify only one row at a time, then use a `RowMajor` sparse matrix, assemble a `SparseVector r;` and assign it to replace the row: `mat.row(i) = r;`.